# Given the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is $R= \{(1,1) ,(4,4)\}$ reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Reflexive is defined as $∀a∈A,$ $a \sim a$ (every element of a is related to itself)
Given the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$, the binary relation, $R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$ is considered reflexive.
Alternatively given the same set, the binary relation, $R=\{(1,1),(1,4),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ is considered not reflexive.
However, if the elements $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ are not present, is $R=\{(1,1),(4,4)\}$ still considered reflexive as it does not contain any other elements with $2 \text{ or } 3$?

Comment: $R$ must contain $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ to be reflexive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be reflexive every element of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ must be related to itself.  If we leave out $(2,2)$ or $(3,3)$ then $2$ is not related to itself and $3$ is not related to itself.

So it is not reflexive.

The reason $\{(1,1),(1,4),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ is not reflexive is *not* because $(1,4)$ was thrown in.  It's not reflexive because $(4,4)$ was taken out.

To be reflexive all of $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)$ must be included.  If all are included it is reflexive.  If not it is not.

SO for example $\{(1,1),(1,4),(2,2),(3,3), (4,4)\}$ *is* reflexive.  (The $(1,4)$ is irrelevent. But each and every one of the $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)$ are essential.)

Answer (score 0):

Reflexive implies that for all elements in the set A (supposing a as the element) then (a,a)∈R.

- In your case, set {1,2,3,4} and R, for R to be reflexive it needs to have (2,2) and (3,3). Since 2,3∈A and (2,2),(3,3) does not belong to R then R is not reflexive.

TIP: A great way to check if R is reflexive is by doing a matrix. A relation R is reflexive if the matrix diagonal elements are 1.